# Unity's HingeJoints: Door changes starting Position and AngleLimits on play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physx

so in the editor, I got an empty DoorObject, which has child objects containing the mesh renderers for the handles, the door etc.
On the DoorObject I put a Rigidbody and a HingeJoint.

Now when I enter play mode, the doors rotates to a different position and with it the angle limits. I don't really understand why, but I suspect it has something to do with the parent objects of DoorObject. Because DoorObject is a child of another hierarchy and those can be scaled to negativ rotated etc.

How could I fix this issue, I just wanna use the transform of DoorObject to define the hinge joint on.

[DoorAssembly is the door im trying to move via hinge joint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMvGe.png)

[Components on DooorAssembly, this looks like it in EditMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHU74.jpg)

[This is what it looks like during play mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgFD.jpg)

The door#3 object is scaled on X to -1. If i change that it works, but I wanna be independet of parent objects.